# Topology whose restriction to some sub-von-Neumann-algebra is its WOT?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $R \subset S$ be distinct von Neumann algebras having a separating vector in the separable Hilbert space $H$ on which they act. In what cases (if any) does there exist a topology $\tau$ on $S$ such that:

(1) every $\tau$-open set meets $R$ (has nonempty intersection with $R$);

(2) $\tau$'s subspace topology on $R$ is $WOT(R)$ (the weak operator topology on $R$ -- see below);

(3) $\tau \not \subseteq WOT(S)$?

I'm going to replace the vague notes I originally posted towards a solution to this question with a simple attempt to clarify it. The weak operator topology (WOT) on the set $B(H)$ of all bounded operators on $H$ is the one whose basic open sets have form

$ \{ T \in B(H) : | \langle (T - T_0) x_i, y_i \rangle | < \epsilon, i = 1, ..., n \}, $

for some $T_0 \in B(H)$, $\epsilon > 0$, and vectors $x_i, y_i$ in $H$. By $WOT(R)$ I mean $WOT$'s subspace topology on $R$ -- that is,

$WOT(R) = \{ O \cap R : O \in WOT \},$

and similarly for $WOT(S)$.

The subspace topology of $WOT(S)$ on $R$ is $WOT(R)$, so $WOT(S)$ meets condition (2) above. However I believe that some nonempty open sets of $WOT(S)$ fail to meet $R$, so neither $WOT(S)$ nor any finer topology satisfies condition (1) above. I also believe there exists a weaker topology than $WOT(S)$ on $S$ that does satisfy (1) and (2). But I don't have any intuition about whether any $\tau$ can jointly satisfy (1), (2), and (3).

Comment: Having to admit I have still not read your question fully, a couple issues: what do you mean by $WOT(R)$? The WOT is an ambient topology, given by an embedding $R\subset B(H)$. Second, you are giving no conditions on $R$ and $S$ that prevent $R=S$, so your condition (3) is bound to fail as presented.